# I am having problems getting my player to jump in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently creating my final project for my coding class, and I have run into a snag in figuring out how to jump. I have used a tutorial video series as reference to my project, here is the link to the jumping episode. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05TCTrpGB-4&t=861s

I most likely have a logic error somewhere but every thing looks fine.

Heres my code:

```
private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

[SerializeField]
private float speed;

[SerializeField]
private Transform[] GroundPoints;

[SerializeField]
private float groundRadius;

[SerializeField]
private LayerMask WhatIsGround;

private bool isGrounded;

private bool Jump;

[SerializeField]
private float JumpForce;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    isGrounded = IsGrounded();

    if(isGrounded && Jump)
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        myRigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce));
    }

    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    HandleMovement(horizontal);

}

private void HandleInput()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Jump = true;
    }
}
//Moving left/right
private void HandleMovement(float horizontal) 
{

    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);

}



private bool IsGrounded()
{
    if(myRigidbody.velocity.y <= 0)
    {
        foreach (Transform point in GroundPoints)
        {
            Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(point.position, groundRadius, WhatIsGround);
                for (int i =0; i < colliders.Length ; i++)
            {
                if(colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: P.S moving left and right works fine.

Comment: You need to tell us what the undesirable behavior is.  Is it _not_ jumping?  Is it jumping but not in the way/direction you expect?  Please provide more details about the specific nature of the problem.

Comment: Sorry. the player is not jumping what so ever.

Comment: What's the value of `JumpForce`?  You might wish to add a few debug logging statements to print out the values to the console so you can see what they are during runtime.

Comment: Also check the `colliders` array in the `IsGrounded` method.  If the call to `OverlapCircleAll` doesn't return any colliders, then `IsGrounded` will never be `true`.

Comment: Ok, so 'JumpForce' is 400, but the debug message I put in shows that the game isn't registering that I have pressed space at all.

Comment: Is there a chat option in this website? this comment thread is getting too lengthy.

Comment: Fixed it!!!! the problem was that I did not put the `HandleInput` Void into the update void! thank you for your help, I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The `HandleInput` was not clarified in `FixedUpdate`. therefore, the code was not read in the update, making the code "invisible". so adding `HandleInput` like I added `HandleMovement` allowed for that code to be read.